# AWS ECS "invalid reference format" on multicontainer app deploy

Tags: docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Cannot compose up in ecs context my multi-container app. In the default context it run. Where am I doing wrong?

```
$ docker compose up  
mysql:8.0.23 resolved to docker.io/library/mysql:8.0.23@sha256:...  
mongo:4.4.3-bionic resolved to docker.io/library/mongo:4.4.3-bionic@sha256:...  
**invalid reference format**
```

My docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
    app:
        container_name: tsb-app
        build:
            context: ..
            dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - mongo
            - mysql
        volumes:
            - tsb_modules:/node_modules
        expose:
            - "80"
    mongo:
        container_name: tsb-mongo
        image: mongo:4.4.3-bionic
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: asdasdasd
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdasdasd
        volumes:
            - tsb_data:/data/db
    mysql:
        container_name: tsb-mysql
        image: mysql:8.0.23
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: asdasdasd
            MYSQL_USER: asdasdasd
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: asdasdasd
        volumes:
            - tsb_logs:/var/lib/
            # Create the required schemas and tabs on first start
            - ./setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
        ports:
            - 3300:3306

volumes:
    tsb_data:
    tsb_logs:
    tsb_modules:
```

my .docker/Dockerfile
FROM node:15.8.0-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .yarnrc yarn.lock prod.env ./.docker/setup.sql ./
RUN yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile
COPY build/ ./build
CMD node build/index.js

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I'm facing the same problem.